# Icecast and darkice combination high-latency

Tags: icecast

I have successfully installed icecast and darkice on my ubuntu machine and was able to stream live on my lan. but to my disappointment it has a 15sec to 20sec delay.This is very poor performance. I don't think it is because of my lan connection because even when i tried to listen in that same ubuntu machine there was still a delay!

I have tried to configure icecast to have no burst-size which means there will be no buffering,this helped me reduce the delay to around 6sec to 8sec.
So please if you have any suggestions or very good configuration values it would be of great help to me.

P.S the format i am streaming is mp3. someone suggested that i should use opus codec but i don't think icecast or darkice support it. and i am streaming in firefox using the html5 audio tag.

Answer (score 1):

This unusual long delay may come from a buffer set as too long in your case.

For Darkice the stream buffer time is defined in your `darkice.cfg` file:

```
bufferSecs      = 1
```

We should leave it to the minimum buffer time needed to avoid choppy playback.